# Change the shape of numbers in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

I want to change the way numbers are displayed in one of the datagridview columns from Arabic to English

I know very well in the event that the Windows language changes the data automatically.
But is there a programmatic way inside the application with the stability of the Windows language to do the operation?
from
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQ1mQ.png)

TO
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D88dL.png)

MY CODE NOT WORK

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")
```

Comment: Those are both Arabic symbols :) You can change the [InputLanguage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.inputlanguage), but you cannot change those symbols from the original Unicode CodePoints to new CodePoints, that's not just a change in input, it's a *translation*. You'll have to do it manually, using the `CultureInfo.NumberFormat.NativeDigits` collection of symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")